# How to get the opposite of Laravel query scopes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

In Laravel, you can define query scopes to define constraints. Is there any way to get the opposite of this scope? Here's a trivial example:

```
function scopeMale($query) {
  return $query->whereGender("M");
}
```

Assume that the only choices for gender are "M" and "F". This therefore will give us a list of all the male students.

```
$male = Students::male()->get();
```

Is there a way in Laravel to define everything else outside the scope? I.e. something like

```
$female = Students::!male()->get();
```

I know that one can always make another scope `female()` but it would be nice to just have something that pertains to the opposite of a given scope.

Comment: well... in your case just create a scope called scopeFemale() .... If there is no obvious opposite use @scrubmx answer

Comment: Any update here, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way that I know of to achieve what you are looking for.

However you can always create a more dynamic query scope to handle both cases:

```
function scopeGender($query, $gender) {
  return $query->whereGender($gender);
}

$male = Students::gender('M')->get();
$female = Students::gender('F')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do someting like this (field,operator,value):

```
$female = Students::where('gender', '<>', 'M')->get();
```

This is an example of book (Learning Laravel's Eloquent, by Francesco Malatesta , PACKT. page 55)

```
    Route::get('...', function(){
        $results = \App\Book::where(function($query){
            $query
                ->where(function($query){
                    // other conditions here...
                    $query->where(function($query){
                        // deeper and deeper in the seas of
                        conditions...
                    });
                })
                ->orWhere('field', 'operator', 'condition');
        })->orWhere(function($query){
            $query
                ->where('field', 'operator', 'condition')
                ->orWhere(function($query){
                    // other conditions here...
                });
        })->get();
        return $results;
    });
```